# SDL - Get native Screen Resolution

Tags: c++, sdl, fullscreen, screen-resolution

My code:

1. *window.cpp*

   ```
   Window::Window(int w, int h, const char *title, const char *icon)
   {
       height = h;
       width = w;

       if(SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) == 0)
       {
           SDL_WM_SetCaption(title, NULL);
           SDL_WM_SetIcon(SDL_LoadBMP(icon),NULL);

           screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 32,
                        SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_RESIZABLE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
           if(screen == NULL)
           {
               running = false;
               return;
           }
           fullscreen = false;
       }
       else
           running = false;
           return;
   }

   Window::Window()
   {
       const SDL_VideoInfo* info = SDL_GetVideoInfo();
       screenWidth = info->current_w;
       screenHeight = info->current_h;
       Window(640, 480, "Flatgu game", "rsc/img/icon.bmp");
   }
   ```
2. *window.h*

   ```
   class Window
   {
   public:
       Window();
       ~Window();

       int getWidth() {return width;}
       int getHeight() {return height;}
       bool isFullscreen() {return fullscreen;}

       void toggleFullscreen();

   private:
       Window(int w, int h, const char *title, const char *icon);

       bool fullscreen, running;
       int height, width, screenWidth, screenHeight;
       SDL_Surface *screen;
   };
   ```

It compiles fine, but then, after compiling, I'm getting this ugly error:
[image: Some address problem]

What's the reason of my problem? Why do I get so weird numbers?

**My aim is to store original screen resolution for further use** (like *toggling to fullscreen*), and I have to do this before calling `SDL_SetVideoMode()`. That's why it is in the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a problem with calling SDL Video Functions before actually initializing SDL.

```
SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING )
```

has to be called **before**

```
SDL_GetVideoInfo();
```

In your case you call `SDL_GetVideoInfo();` first

```
const SDL_VideoInfo* info = SDL_GetVideoInfo();   //<-- calls SDL_GetVideoInfo();   
screenWidth = info->current_w;
screenHeight = info->current_h;
Window(640, 480, "Flatgu game", "rsc/img/icon.bmp");    //<-- initializes SDL
```

So the solution is simple; make the call `SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING )` immediately at the start of your program, then you can call `SDL_GetVideoInfo();` as much as you like.
You will have to restructure your class Window slightly.

Comment: That no longer works with SDL2. See [a newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33393689/18920490)

Answer (score 3):

To get the *best* video mode call `SDL_GetVideoInfo` before setting up the video (before calling `SDL_SetVideoMode`).

But you still have to initialize the video subsystem before calling it (`SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)`).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but there's a big mistake in the code.

```
Window(640, 480, "Flatgu game", "rsc/img/icon.bmp");
```

creates a nameless instance of a Window, so the instance that calls it will still have uninitialized variables. It looks like you were trying to use delegating constructors, but in that case the call to the other constructor must be in the member initializer list.
See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961037/delegate-constructor-c).