# How to get screen size in SDL

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm trying to make a program using SDL and C++. How can I get screen's width and height in pixels in SDL?I'm trying to get screen's width not the window's width.                                                                                                      .                                                                                           .                                                                                      .

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575500/sdl-get-native-screen-resolution

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In SDL2, use [`SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode) or [`SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode) depending on your needs. Usage example:

```
SDL_DisplayMode DM;
SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode(0, &DM);
auto Width = DM.w;
auto Height = DM.h;
```

On high-DPI displays this will return the virtual resolution, not the physical resolution.

From the SDL2 wiki:

> There's a difference between [[SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode)()] and [SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode)() when SDL runs fullscreen and has changed the resolution. In that case [[SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode)()] will return the previous native display mode, and not the current display mode.

Answer (score 10):

**On Fullscreen:** it can be done really easily using `SDL_GetRendererOutputSize`

You just have to pass in a your `SDL_Renderer*` like so:

```
int w, h;

SDL_GetRendererOutputSize(renderer, &w, &h);
```

> void SDL_GetRendererOutputSize(SDL_Renderer* renderer,
>                          int*        w,
>                          int*        h)

**renderer** a rendering context

**w**
a pointer filled in with the width of the renderer

**h**
a pointer filled in with the height of the renderer

**On Non-Fullscreen:**

Using `SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode()`

```
SDL_DisplayMode dm;

if (SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode(0, &dm) != 0)
{
     SDL_Log("SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode failed: %s", SDL_GetError());
     return 1;
}

int w, h;
w = dm.w;
h = dm.h;
```

Just please do an error checking! Or you'll hate your life when `SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode` fails!