# Scoping issues when chaining class constructors

Tags: c++, class, constructor, scope

Why does the following not work when chaining constructors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class cls {
public:
    cls()           {cls(5);}       // want to resize v to 5
    cls(int n)      {v.resize(n);}
    std::vector<int> v;
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    cls x, y(5);
    std::cout << x.v.size() << std::endl;   // prints 0 <- expected 5
    std::cout << y.v.size();                // prints 5
    return 0;
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/30UBzS

I expected both objects to have a `v` of size 5. What's wrong?

Reason I want to do this is because writing separate `cls()` and `cls(n)` ctors would duplicate a lot of code.

Comment: is  `{cls(5);} ` a typo?. It should be `v.resize(5)`;

Comment: That's my point, I wanted the 2nd constructor to handle it. It was hoping to avoid code repetition, as I've actually got much more than just a `v.resize` in my full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `cls(5);` inside of the `cls::cls()` constructor is not doing what you think it is doing. It is creating a temporary variable using the second `cls` constructor which is destroyed at `;`.

You can use C++11's delegating constructors to achieve what you want:

```
cls() : cls(5) { }
```

If you don't have a compiler that supports C++11, you can pull the common initialisation out into another function, and have both constructors call that:

```
class cls {
public:
    cls()           { init(5); }
    cls(int n)      { init(n); }
    std::vector<int> v;
private:
    void init(int n) { v.resize(n); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
cls()  {cls(5);}
```

to

```
cls()  {v.resize(5);}
```

Otherwise you are creating new temporary `cls` in the constructor and ignoring it.

---

OR If you want to [**`delegate the constructor`**](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/b-5-delegating-constructors/) (C++11) do it like this

```
cls() : cls(5)  {} 
//   ^^   ^
//        | use cls(int n)
```

delegated constructor are allowed only in the [**`member initialization`**](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?464084-C-General-What-is-the-initialization-list-and-why-should-I-use-it) list of a constructor.

Comment: So I can't just call `cls(n)` like a normal function? What about if I want `cls() {dostuff(); cls(5); ...}`?

Comment: @MiloChen `cls(5)` creates a new class normally. Except when it is in the member initialization list of another constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```
class cls
{
public:
       cls()
       :
       v( 5 ){}               // create v that contains 5 elements ( each initialized to 0 ) - note: this is NOT resizing

        explicit cls( const int size )
        :
        v( size ){}
private:       
        std::vector<int> v;
};
```

Of course, if you need resizing feature on the living object, you will need a 'resize' method already mentioned in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

`cal(5)` creates a completely different object, in fact it's a temporary meaning the object will be destroyed at the end of its encapsulation expression. Or it might not be called at all due to compiler optimization.

But with that aside, the constructor call only affects the temporary and not the original object calling the constructor.

If your intention was to make the code shorter, you should create a member function that does this (assuming your compiler doesn't support C++11, in which case you could simply use the **[Delegating Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961037/delegate-constructor-c)** feature):

```
class cls
{
    void resize(int n)
    {
        v.resize(n);
    }

    public:
        cls()           { resize(5); }
        cls(int n)      { resize(n); }
        std::vector<int> v;
};
```