# Default constructor with no inputs

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am trying to create a class which has a constructor with no input arguments - I was trying to test it by printing to the screen. However unless I give the constructor an input the constructor gets skipped straight over - the debug mode doesn't even register it as a line - can anyone shed light on this?

Also, is it possible to call the constructor of another class from inside a constructor/function belonging to a different class?

Header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class rain
{
public:
    rain(); 
    void update();
    ~rain();

private:

};
```

Source file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "rain.h"
#include "Digital Rain.h"
#include "Stream.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Stream.h"



using namespace std;

int screen_width = 79;

rain::rain()
{
    cout << "hi" << endl;
}


void rain::update()
{
    Sleep(5);
}



rain::~rain()
{
}
```

Comment: Can you show some example of you how create an instance of your class? Also, yes you can have another class's constructor do work for you (in C++11 or newer) using [delegating constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961037/delegate-constructor-c)

Comment: @Cyber, Within the same class, yes. I think what the OP is asking about is a constructor initializer list. If not that, then it's as simple as creating an object like anywhere else.

Comment: most vexing parse on the way ?

Comment: @Cyber You can't delegate to a different class's constructor! Only to another constructor of the same class.

Comment: @MattMcNabb You are correct, I worded that statement poorly, I'll edit it. Edit: no I won't, it seems to be uneditable after a few minutes :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at a piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

class rain {
    public:
        rain();
};

rain::rain() {
    std::cout << "hi\n";
}

int main() {
    rain x();
    rain y;
}
```

When we run this, we'll see `hi` on the output only once. This is because of the [**Most Vexing Parse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

So:

- `x` is actually a **function declaration** for a function that takes no arguments and returns a `rain` object.
- `y` is actually a `rain` object.

Additionally, your compiler might warn you about this situation. `clang` for example will report:

```
asdd.cc:26:11: warning: empty parentheses interpreted as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
    rain x();
          ^~
asdd.cc:26:11: note: remove parentheses to declare a variable
    rain x();
          ^~
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: @chris: I've made an edit to my description of `x`. If it's still wrong (or could be better) please feel free to edit it.

Comment: So how exactly am I supposed to call the function? use rain y; ? why is this any different from including inputs? would that not be the same as declaring a function with inputs?

Comment: @Mauvai: I'm sorry. I don't understand your question. If you'd like to create an object of type `rain`, while using a no-argument constructor, you should type `rain obj;`, and use no parentheses. The reason behind this can be seen by reading about the "most vexing parse" (which I linked to the wikipedia article, but there are thousands of articles on the internet about this).

Comment: Yes that was my question - it worked too, obviously. thanks :)

I did read the most vexing parse, but only just figured out why this only applied to no input constructors.

Comment: Also, i was using Visual Studios 2013, and it did _not_ warn me of this situation