# Should I outsource allocation algorithm? (RAII)

Tags: c++, memory-management, raii

Right now my class has a **constructor**, **copy constructor** and **copy assignment operator** which **all do the same thing at first** (allocating memory). The destructor is deallocating the memory.

```
class Register
{
public:
    Register()
    {
        _trampoline_address = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(VirtualAlloc(nullptr, _trampoline_size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE));
        if (_trampoline_address == nullptr)
        {
            throw my_exception("Could not allocate memory for trampoline function.");
        }

        //....
    }
    ~Register()
    {
        if (_trampoline_address != nullptr)
        {
            debug(VirtualFree(_trampoline_address, 0, MEM_RELEASE));
        }
    }
    Register(const Register& other)
    {
        _trampoline_address = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(VirtualAlloc(nullptr, _trampoline_size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE));
        if (_trampoline_address == nullptr)
        {
            throw my_exception("Could not allocate memory for trampoline function.");
        }

        //...
    }
    Register& operator= (const Register& other)
    {
        _trampoline_address = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(VirtualAlloc(nullptr, _trampoline_size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE));
        if (_trampoline_address == nullptr)
        {
            throw my_exception("Could not allocate memory for trampoline function.");
        }

        //....
    }

private:
    BYTE* _trampoline_address;
    static const int _trampoline_size = 20;
};
```

I thought about outsourcing the allocation algorithm **because I use it 3 times**, but I don't want that other instances of the same class type can access that function.

So what would be the proper solution to allocate memory in 3 functions in a RAII class?

Comment: _"but I don't want that other instances of the same class type can access that function."_ Do you mean inherited classes? I don't get this restriction, as written in the context. Other than that you can simply provide a private function in the class that is used by all of the constructors.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "outsource"? That word doesn't have a specific meaning in C++.

Comment: You could make it a private function.  If you want to use it in the class initializer list you could make it a private static function.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty I had trouble translating the word into english. What I mean is that I create a new function that does the allocation for me, Then I call that function from my ctor, copy ctor and copy assignment operator.

Comment: @Tobi_R _"What I mean is that I create a new function that does the allocation for me ..."_ As mentioned you can do this. Did you meet any problems, when trying so?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's exactly what I thought about. But If I do that, other instances of my class 'Register' will have access to that function. So they could possibly call that "allocate memory function" on another object.

Comment: @Tobi_R _"other instances of my class"_ Again: Please elaborate about this! It makes no sense for me. Every instance of your class needs to call that function (it's in the constructor).

Comment: @Tobi_R I think you are confused on how class member functions work.  The member function of a class can modify the values of the object that called it and any instance that was passed to the function.  I cant call `foo` on one instance and have it modify another instance unless I pass that other instance to foo.

Comment: @NathanOliver Indeed I am confused, but I think the private function mentioned multiple times is the best solution in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct Register {
  Register():
    _trampoline_address(allocate())
  {}
  Register(Register const& o):
    Register() // forward to default ctor
  {
    copy_data_from(o);
  }
  ~Register() {
    if (_trampoline_address)
      debug(VirtualFree(_trampoline_address, 0, MEM_RELEASE));
  }
  Register& operator= (const Register& o) {
    if (this != std::addressof(o))
      copy_data_from(o);
    return *this;
  }
private:
  void copy_data_from(Register const& o) {
    Assert(_tranpoline_address);
    // ...
  }
  static BYTE* allocate() {
    return reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(
      VirtualAlloc(nullptr, _trampoline_size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)
    );
  }
  BYTE* _trampoline_address;
  static const/*expr*/ int _trampoline_size = 20;
};
```

there is only one call to `allocate`, but I still put it in a `static private` method because it is messy.

I also wrote `copy_data_from`, because it will be used twice (once in copy-ctor, once in assignment).

I personally would be tempted to have `Register()` leave you with an empty buffer, only filled when used.  Read functions would have to check for `nullptr` and `allocate()` if it was missing: but they have to check for `nullptr` anyhow.  The result is a more efficient move-ctor and move-assign, creating empty arrays (and populating later) is far more efficient, etc.

In this case, `allocate()` turns out to be more useful.  You can even have `ensure_allocated()`, which initializes `_tranpoline_address` if `nullptr`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was just wondering why should I even make the allocate function static?

Comment: @Tobi_R because `static` states "I don't consume any state of this object".  It makes understanding the function easier.  It isn't "why use static", but rather "there is no reason not to use static".

Comment: okay I get it! So if my allocate_memory would directly change the _trampoline_address variable it shouldn't be static? (I don't want to do this but just for the understanding)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `private static` function to help with the memory allocation:

```
static BYTE* allocate()
{
    BTYE* ptr = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(VirtualAlloc(nullptr, _trampoline_size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE));
    if (ptr == nullptr)
    {
        throw my_exception("Could not allocate memory for trampoline function.");
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Then, the constructors can be simplified to:

```
Register() : _trampoline_address(allocate()) { }

Register(const Register& other) : _trampoline_address(allocate()) { }
```

However, the copy assignment operator needs a little bit more work. First of all, it's not clear from your posted code, what are the semantics of the assignment operator. Are you supposed to copy the data from the RHS to the LHS? If not, what role does the RHS play in the assignment operation? What are you supposed to do with the memory owned by the LHS?

```
Register& operator= (const Register& other)
{
   // Prevent messing with memory when dealing with self-assignment.
   if ( this != &other )
   {
      // Deal with the semantics of the operation.
   }
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: The copy assignment operator should allocate new memory on the lhs and copy the data of the rhs to the lhs. I am gonna add that check to the assignment operator!

Comment: Why do you need to allocate new memory? Why not re-use the memory owned by the object?

Comment: You are right, I got the purpose of the copy assignment operator wrong. So a simple copy algorithm should probably be enough!

Comment: @Tobi_R Also read this article for the subtleties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of two things:

1. Create a `private` function, then call it in each constructor.  This still allows other member functions of the class to call the function after construction, but that should be OK (just don't call it!).  *Subclasses* cannot call a class's private members, so you should be fine.
2. Use [delegated constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13961100/1830736).  Perform the allocation in one constructor, then call that constructor from the others.  Obviously, nobody can call a constructor explicitly, so your concern should be taken care of.  Possible caveat: you will need to use a C++11 compliant compiler.

Comment: Thanks, I am gonna look into the delegated constructors!